# Where would I ask a question about punctuation for several different languages?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Specifically, are there languages besides French that require a space before certain punctuation marks? I see communities for specific languages and communities that deal with writing and grammar (but those are all for English.) But not a place to post a question like this.

Comment: [Slightly related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark#comment206109_4645)

Answer (score 2):

[Linguistics Stack Exchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com) seems to fit your description. [The /help/on-topic page](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) links to [this meta post](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/332), which includes "Syntax" and other related topics.

Comment: Ok. I saw a similar question to mine in there, but it was just about one language and people in there were saying it didn't belong in Linguistics. :-)

Comment: @MeganSullivan If you're in doubt, you can always [ask on their per-site meta](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Shoot. Need rep there to ask a question. Thanks for helping, though.